# Unit testing PHAsset and permissions

Tags: ios, unit-testing, phasset, photosframework

I'm developing a framework, and I would like to unit test the part of the framework that helps fetching assets from the camera roll.

I've added the permissions to the test module `Info.plist` , but I can't get the permission granted to access the camera roll when I run the test. Should I use UI Test Case instead ?

How can you test multimedia functionalities on PHAssets or AVAssets ?

Comment: You shouldn't test Apple's code _at all_. You _know_ what it does. The only thing you need to test is the logic of _your_ code, and that is something you can do entirely with mocks. So for example, don't test the actual process of obtaining permission; test the _logic_ of obtaining permission. And so on.

Comment: @matt You're right, I totally agree. But how can I test a PHAsset if I can't get it from the camera roll ?